# .htaccess 301 redirect dynamic URL with regex?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, regular-expression

How to do this with regular expression?

```
Old -> New
http://www.example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/tool-model-10   -> http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-10
http://www.example.com/cat1/cat2/cat4/tool-model-11   -> http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-11
http://www.example.com/cat1/cat2/tool-model-12        -> http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-12
http://www.example.com/cat5/cat6/tool-model-13        -> http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-13
http://www.example.com/cat7/tool-model-14             -> http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-14
```

I've tried this:

```
Redirect 301 /cat1/cat2/cat3/tool-model-10 http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-10
Redirect 301 /cat1/cat2/cat4/tool-model-11 http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-11 
Redirect 301 /cat1/cat2/tool-model-12      http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-12 
Redirect 301 /cat5/cat6/tool-model-13      http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-13
Redirect 301 /cat7/tool-model-14           http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-14
```

I understand that logiс should be:

1. divide URL string on 2 strings: 1 and 2
2. If first URL string 1 contains `tool-model-` at the end *AND* does not contain `tool` catalog at the beginning then make redirect to 
   `http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-` *PLUS* two digits (string 2).

Comment: "I've tried this" - And what was the problem with that? Did it do anything? Did you get an error? Where did you try it? ...or are you wanting to combine these rules into a single directive?

Comment: It is working, but when there are 20 models + structure of catalogs changed several times I got 100 lines with   standard redirect like Redirect 301 /old-cat/tool-model-15  http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-15 instead of 2-3 lines with regexp for all. So I want to combine in single directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If first url string 1 contain "tool-model-" at the end AND does not contain "tool" catalog at the beginning make redirect to `http://www.example.com/tool/tool-model-` *PLUS* two digits (string 2)

To simplify/combine your redirects into a single ruleset I would use mod_rewrite, rather than mod_alias (`Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`) since you want a condition that says `does not contain "tool"` (which is tricky with `RedirectMatch`). Try something like the following in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tool/
RewriteRule /(tool-model-\d\d)$ /tool/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This states for any URL that ends `/tool-model-NN` and does not start `/tool/` then redirect to `/tool/tool-model-NN`. `$1` in the *substitution* is a backreference to the captured group (ie. `(tool-model-\d\d)`) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (a regex).

NB: I've used a `302` (temporary) redirect above. Change this to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. 301 redirects are cached by the browser, so can make testing awkward. (So, you will need to clear your browser cache before testing the above directives.)

Also, if you are currently using mod_alias `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`) for other redirects then it would be advisable to also convert these to mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directives. The reason being that different modules run at different times, regardless of the order in the `.htaccess` file. So, you can get some unexpected conflicts by combining redirects from both modules.

Comment: Thank you, @w3dk. If I want to add comparison of the end URL with "tool-model-\d\d" is it correct: `code`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(tool-model-\d\d)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tool/
RewriteRule /(tool-model-\d\d)$ /tool/$1 [R=302,L]`code`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with that last bit of code? It's valid, but it's really no different to the code I posted above, except that the `RewriteCond` directive you added is superfluous (that `RewriteCond` directive does the same as what the `RewriteRule` pattern does). (?)

Comment: NB: I am a newbie in regexp. I used added RewriteCond directive for speedup. For example if URL does not contain (tool-model-\d\d) interpreter should look more this block of code, go to next. May be I am not rigth because win in time too small. Just only for time and resources economy

Comment: Ah OK. However, mod_rewrite does not work like that. The `RewriteRule` directive is actually processed first. Only when the `RewriteRule` pattern matches the URL-path do the preceding `RewriteCond` directives get processed. (This is not a regexp thing, but a mod_rewrite thing.) So, the additional `RewriteCond` would actually be a "slow-down" (if anything), not a "speedup". Although, as you suggest, any difference in timing in this respect is likely to be "too small" to notice - in this instance anyway.