# .htaccess regex 301 redirect after changing site structure?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, regular-expression

I`m trying to convert standard 301 redirects using regexp after several changes of categories structures.

How to do this with regular expression?

```
Old -> New
http://www.example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/bla1-bla2-bla3-machine-ab123 -> http://www.example.com/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123
http://www.example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/bla4-bla5-bla6-machine-123   -> http://www.example.com/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123
http://www.example.com/cat4/cat5/bla7-bla8-bla9-machine-123        -> http://www.example.com/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123
```

Now I use this:

```
Redirect 301 /cat1/cat2/cat3/bla1-bla2-bla3-machine-ab123 http://www.example.com/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123
Redirect 301 /cat1/cat2/cat3/bla4-bla5-bla6-machine-123   http://www.example.com/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123
Redirect 301 /cat4/cat5/bla7-bla8-bla9-machine-123        http://www.example.com/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123
```

I want to realize next algorithm:
If URL contain *machine-ab123* or *machine-123* at end of url
and full url do not equal final version of url */cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123*
rewrite it to final version */cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123*

Looking on previous answer for me (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98981/69774) I made such contruction:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(machine-ab123|machine-123)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123
RewriteRule /(machine-ab123|machine-123)$ /cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123 [R=301,L]
```

Not working, where could be mistake?

By the way, if I need to check does URL contain *machine-ab123* or *machine-123* not only at end of url, but also in any position, for example,

```
/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-machine-ab123-bla22-bla33
/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-machine-ab123-bla33
```

how regexp should be changed?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, may will be useful for somebody.

If searched substring located at the end of URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)(machine-ab123|machine-123)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123
RewriteRule ^(.*)(machine-ab123|machine-123)$ /cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123 [R=301,L]
```

If searched substring located in the middle of URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)(machine-ab123|machine-123)(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123
RewriteRule ^(.*)(machine-ab123|machine-123)(.*)$ /cat11/cat22/cat33/bla11-bla22-bla33-machine-ab123 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: As [just mentioned in a comment on your other question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98978/htaccess-301-redirect-dynamic-url-with-regex#comment123837_98981), the first `RewriteCond` directive on both your rules is not required here. You are already performing this check in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ - which is more efficient. Also, the regexp can be tidied... to match _something_ anywhere in the string (URL) you can simply use the regexp `something` (no _anchors_ or special meta chars required). There is no need for the more "complex" `^(.*)something(.*)$`.